# Why WordPress display menus automatically?

Tags: wordpress, menu

I have just installed WordPress 4.7 and I added some pages.
Then I can see page list in header.
I didn't create any menus in admin panel and why is it?
Do they add menus in header automatically if there is no menu?

Answer (score 0):

I'd say in depends heavily on the theme you're using. If the theme has a feature such as a default menu generated form the entire list of published pages it might be the case.

In order to know which theme you are using, go into the admin then into the Appearance menu and the themes submenu.

If it is a custom theme you bought, you might have to refer to its documentation or go inside the code to check for yourself. If it is a default theme like twenty-sixteen you should be able to modify the behavior from the theme configuration in the admin.